# How to pass a list as an argument in python

Tags: python

I am new to python and I was coding in C++ for two years. I want to pass a list as an argument in a function to display all the stuff inside in different lines (Actually I want to make my own function just to display the stuff)

```
myvar = [1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 4, 9, 5, 10]

def displaylist(paramlist):
    tempindex = 0
    for i in paramlist:
        print paramlist[tempindex]
        tempindex += 1

displaylist(myvar)
```

This is what I wrote and I am getting this:

```
1
4
5
3
7
4
9
5
10
```

This is not the expected output. What have I done wrong.

NOTE: I am new to this language.

Edit: I apologize for the inconvenience but it showed the exact output I wanted, I didn't notice it because of my negligence. Please flag this question so that it gets deleted

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Question makes no sense, it is not clear what you want to know

Comment: I think OP doesn't know that `print` in python adds a `\n` at the end. In C++ you need to explicitly add the `\n` (I'm not a 100% sure on this one).

Comment: "to display all the stuff inside in different lines"  - (all stuff inside == elements of list)  => your output exactly does this :)

Answer (score 7):

This looks like the expected output to me. Note a bit more pythony way to write the code might be

```
myvar = [1,4,5,3,7,4,9,5,10]

def displaylist(paramlist):
    for p in paramlist:
        print p

displaylist(myvar)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print('\n'.join(str(e) for e in ls))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is '\n' you can do it like this, but it's strange.

```
myvar = [1, 4, 5, 3, 7, 4, 9, 5, 10]


def displaylist(paramlist):
    out_str = reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), myvar)
    print out_str

displaylist(myvar)
```

out:

```
1453749510
```

Comment: Well you can also just use `for i in paramlist: print i,` and the comma prevents newlines, though it adds spaces. You can use `sys.stdout.write(i)` to avoid having even a space.

Answer (score 0):

Following the same line as Wujo, this is a simple solution:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def displaylist(paramlist):
    list = ''
    for p in paramlist:
        list += str(p)
    print list
```

output: `12345`